# Dynamically change size of image overlay in video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to add a logo (over a video) that grows during the video at a steady rate. I am able to position and overlay the video where I need it with the Transform tool but I can't find a method to animate the change in the tools that are available. I wonder if anyone knows a way to reach this goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the mouse cursor above the slider, what you adjust and hit I to insert a keyframe.

Comment: I don't understand what this means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This tutorial explains well. https://youtu.be/u_m4X6Gyph0